# Terraform: Creating GCP Project using Shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, terraform

I've been working through this for what feels like an eternity now.. so the host project already exists.. and has all the VPN's and networking set up. I am looking to create a new project, through Terraform and allowing it to use the host projects shared VPC.

Every time I run up against a problem and end up resolving it, I just run up against another one.

Right now I'm seeing:

```
google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project.project: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/intacct-staging-db3b7e7a' was not found, notFound
* google_compute_instance.dokku: 1 error(s) occurred:
```

As well as:

```
 google_compute_instance.dokku: Error loading zone 'europe-west2-a': googleapi: Error 404: Failed to find project intacct-staging, notFound
```

I was originally convinced it was ordering, which is why I was playing around with `depends_on` configurations, to try and sort out the order. That hasn't seemed to resolve it.

Reading it simply, `google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project` doesn't exist as far as `google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project` is concerned. Even though I've added the following to `google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project`:

```
depends_on = ["google_project.project",
    "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host_project",
  ]
```

Perhaps, because the host project already exists I should use `data` to refer to it instead of `resource`?

My full TF File is here:

```
provider "google" {
 region = "${var.gcp_region}"
 credentials = "${file("./creds/serviceaccount.json")}"
}
resource "random_id" "id" {
 byte_length = 4
 prefix      = "${var.project_name}-"
}
resource "google_project" "project" {
 name            = "${var.project_name}"
 project_id      = "${random_id.id.hex}"
 billing_account = "${var.billing_account}"
 org_id          = "${var.org_id}"
}
resource "google_project_services" "project" {
  project = "${google_project.project.project_id}"
  services = [
    "compute.googleapis.com"
  ]
  depends_on = [ "google_project.project" ]
}
# resource "google_service_account" "service-account" {
#   account_id   = "intacct-staging-service"
#   display_name = "Service Account for the intacct staging app"
# }
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host_project" {
  project    = "${var.vpc_parent}"
}
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" "project" {
  host_project    = "${google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host_project.project}"
  service_project = "${google_project.project.project_id}"

  depends_on = ["google_project.project",
    "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host_project",
  ]
}

resource "google_compute_address" "dokku" {
  name = "fr-intacct-staging-ip"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
  project = "${google_project.project.project_id}"
  depends_on = [ "google_project_services.project" ]
}
resource "google_compute_instance" "dokku" {
  project                   = "${google_project.project.name}"
  name                      = "dokku-host"
  machine_type              = "${var.comp_type}"
  zone                      = "${var.gcp_zone}"
  allow_stopping_for_update = "true"

  tags = ["intacct"]

  # Install Dokku
  metadata_startup_script   = <<SCRIPT
sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin no/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd restart
SCRIPT

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "${var.compute_image}"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork         = "${var.subnetwork}"
    subnetwork_project = "${var.vpc_parent}"
    access_config      = {
      nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.dokku.address}"
    }
  }
  metadata {
    sshKeys = "root:${file("./id_rsa.pub")}"
  }
}
```

EDIT:

As discussed below I was able to resolve the latter project not found error by changing the reference to `project_id` instead of `name` as name does not include the random hex.

I'm now also seeing another error, referring to the static IP. The network interface is configured to use the subnetwork from the Host VPC...

```
network_interface {
    subnetwork         = "${var.subnetwork}"
    subnetwork_project = "${var.vpc_parent}"
    access_config      = {
      nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.dokku.address}"
   }
}
```

The IP is setup here:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "dokku" {
  name = "fr-intacct-staging-ip"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
  project = "${google_project.project.project_id}"
}
```

The IP should really be in the host project, which I've tried.. and when I do I get an error saying that cross-project is not allowed with this resource.

When I change to the above, it also errors saying that the new project is now capable of handling API Calls. Which I suppose would make sense as I only allowed compute API calls per the `google_project_services` resource.

I'll try allowing network API calls and see if that works, but I'm thinking the external IP needs to be in the host project's shared VPC?

Comment: The second error was easily resolvable by changing `project                   = "${google_project.project.name}"` to `project                   = "${google_project.project.project_id}"` however I still seem to be coming across the problem regarding the project not existing. And now an issue suggesting it the compute_instance can't see the subnetwork from the host VPC. Added new error to original post.

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a grab bag of issues with no clear request of what you want or need help with. It is unclear what you are are asking, so it will be very difficult for someone to provide an acceptable answer. Please read this guide and clean up your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

For anyone encountering the same problem, in my case the project not found error was solved just by enabling the Compute Engine API.